# Wordpress page numbers and .htaccess ModRewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

we're getting quite a few errors popping up in webmaster tools. Our homepage paginated pages are showing up without the page prefix i.e. 17/ instead of page/17/

Can anyone help me write a rule to redirect these pages so the errors don't keep popping up?

We need to turn…

http://wwwexample.com/17/

into…

http://wwwexample.com/page/17/

We only need this to work for the homepage though as the pagination is working fine for the rest of the site i.e.

www.example.com/category/snails/17/ (This is working properly)

I'm not hot on mod rewrite and would like to start learning more about it.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these rules before your wordpress rules in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ /page/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works an absolute treat Jon, thanks very much.

What do the separate bits mean?